# TASM pointer position comparison

Tags: assembly, tasm

I am down to my last section of code for a program that checks if a given line is a palindrome. However, I have one thing that I need help with.

I have pointers si and di, pointing at the first and last characters of the line. I use them to compare the characters, then move on. However, I also need to compare the positions of the pointers themselves, so I know where I need to stop as I know that the line is a palindrome.

Here is the segment of code that does the comparing.

```
is_pol PROC near
mov si, offset currentline
mov di, offset currentline
add di, currentline_offset

comparesi:
    cmp si, 'a'         
        jl notsmallsi
    cmp si, 'z'
    jg notsymbolsi
    jmp comparedi
notsmallsi:
    cmp si, 'A'
    jl notlargesi
    cmp si, 'Z'
    jg notsymbolsi
    jmp comparedi
notlargesi:
    cmp si, '0'
    jl notsymbolsi
    cmp si, '9'
    jg notsymbolsi
    jmp comparedi
notsymbolsi:
    inc si
    jmp comparesi
comparedi:
    cmp di, 'a'
    jl notsmalldi
    cmp di, 'z'
    jg notsymboldi
    jmp compare
notsmalldi:
    cmp di, 'A'
    jl notlargedi
    cmp di, 'Z'
    jg notsymboldi
    jmp compare
notlargedi:
    cmp di, '0'
    jl notsymboldi
    cmp di, '9'
    jg notsymboldi
    jmp compare
notsymboldi:
    dec di
    jmp comparedi
compare:
    cmp si, di
    jne no_palindrome
    inc si
    dec di

    jmp is_palindrome
    jmp comparesi

no_palindrome:
    lea dx, not_palindrome
    mov cx, 30
    ret

is_palindrome:
    lea dx, palindrome
    mov cx, 30
    ret
is_pol ENDP
```

The section of code that is missing is the one between "dec di" and "jmp is_palindrome"

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SI` and `DI` **are** the pointers. Since a pointer is just a memory address, they contain "the positions of the pointers themselves". You can compare them and break the loop if the memory address of the left started incrementing pointer is below or equal than the memory address of the right started decrementing point, i.e. `SI`<=`DI`.

A huge mistake: To compare the values of the memory, you have to dereference the pointers. At the moment you compare the pointers with a character (`cmp si, 'a'`). Dereference `SI` or `DI` with brackets and add a size specification: `cmp byte ptr [si], 'a'`.